# Changing the tool tip for the TinyMCE removeformatting button

Tags: tinymce-4

I'd like to change the tool tip for the TinyMCE 4 "removeformatting" button:

[image]

from "Clear formatting" to "Clear selected formatting."  But I'm not able to find where in the TinyMCE code this button is defined.

Can someone point me to the ed.addButton code for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it the line you are looking for is:

```
<span id="mceu_61-text" class="mce-text">Clear formatting</span>
```

So a simple JS search and rewrite the inner HTML would work. But this button clears all formatting on the text if nothing is selected or only clears the selected text if there is a selection. (Note the id of the element will change depending on what tool bars you have loaded, that line was taken from a full featured demo)

Though the actual hard coded string seems to be located in

> tinymce/classes/ui/FormatControls.js

on line 300

```
removeformat: ['Clear formatting', 'RemoveFormat'],
```

Comment: Hi Chris,
I don't have a "/classes/ui/FormatControls.js" under my tinymce directory but I did find the above removeformat line in my tinymce.js file, and changing 'Clear formatting' to 'Clear selected formatting' worked!

Regarding the operation of the button, if I select one word and change the color to green and then select outside of all text and select Clear formatting, nothing happens.  But if I select the green word and select Clear formatting it goes back to black. So I'm not seeing the behavior you describe, which is why my new tool tip seems to me to be more accurate.  - Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are using an out of date version or the code implementation hasn't been done exactly right then. Try looking at the version of your tmce library against the current version. Might be some big differences but looks like it's worth the upgrade (Personal oppinion).

Answer (score 0):

One way you can change these is to use a language file for `en_US` and put replacements there.  To make this work you need to do 2 things:

**1 - Add a language configuration option to your init:**

```
tinymce.init({ 
  selector: '#myTextArea',
  language: 'en_US',   //Force custom translations of button/menu text in English.
  ...
});
```

**2 - Add a `en_US.js` file to your `langs` folder within TinyMCE.**
This file is where TinyMCE looks for language translations so if you tell TinyMCE explicitly to use the `en_US` language it will look in the `langs` folder for a JS file of the same name as the language.  You can then put updated translations in that file:

```
tinymce.addI18n('en_US',{
  "Clear formatting": "Custom Clear Formatting Text"
});
```

To see all your options for what you can change just grab a language file from here:  https://www.tinymce.com/download/language-packages/  The label on the left is the "key" and the value on the right is the "value".  The "key" is effectively what you get in English when you don't include a reference to a language in the `tinymce.init({})` call..

The advantage of this is that you are not changing the TinyMCE code itself so this makes updating TinyMCE easier as you don't need to keep recreating your changes.